# Confusing output with pandas rolling window with datetime64[us] dtype

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rolling-computation

I get confusing results from `pandas.rolling()` when the dtype is `datetime64[us]`. Pandas version is 2.1.1. Let `df` be the dataframe

```
          day  x
0  2021-01-01  3
1  2021-01-02  2
2  2021-01-03  1
3  2021-01-05  4
4  2021-01-08  2
5  2021-01-14  5
6  2021-01-15  6
7  2021-01-16  1
8  2021-01-19  5
9  2021-01-20  2
```

Its dtypes are:

```
day    datetime64[ns]
x               int64
dtype: object
```

We specify a rolling window of length **3 days**:

```py
df.rolling("3d", on="day", center=True)["x"].sum()
```

Output is as expected:

```
0     5.0
1     6.0
2     3.0
3     4.0
4     2.0
5    11.0
6    12.0
7     7.0
8     7.0
9     7.0
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Let us repeat this after casting the dtype `datetime64[ns]` to `datetime64[us]`:

```py
df["day"] = df["day"].astype("datetime64[us]")
```

Using the exact same code as above for the rolling window now gives:

```
0    31.0
1    31.0
2    31.0
3    31.0
4    31.0
5    31.0
6    31.0
7    31.0
8    31.0
9    31.0
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce it on pandas 2.1.2, make sure to use a recent version:

```
print(pd.__version__)
2.1.2

df["day"] = df["day"].astype("datetime64[us]")
print(df.dtypes)
day    datetime64[us]
x               int64
dtype: object

df.rolling("3d", on="day", center=True)["x"].sum()
0     5.0
1     6.0
2     3.0
3     4.0
4     2.0
5    11.0
6    12.0
7     7.0
8     7.0
9     7.0
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Interesting. I just did a clean install of miniconda. My pandas version is 2.1.1. I will try to update to 2.1.2.

Comment: Upgraded from pandas 2.1.1 to pandas 2.1.3. The problem is now gone. On another machine (production server) we run pandas 1.4.4. Here the casting to datetime64[us] does not work at all. It remains datatime64[ns]. Note: I am not interested is the us version, it was an artifact of another part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the pandas version problem. When I use pandas version 2.1.1 it reproduces the same problem, when I use pandas version 2.1.2 the problem disappears. Moreover When I use old python version 1.3.5, datetime64[us] will not be transfered and it remains datetime64[ns].